# windows.h and MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, afx

Why can't I include windows.h in afx(MFC) projects?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically, MFC application code includes `afx.h` or `afxwin.h` (the latter includes former). First two lines of `windows.h` are

```
#ifndef _WINDOWS_
#define _WINDOWS_
```

which means that `_WINDOWS_` becomes defined if this header is included. 
`Afx.h` includes `afxver_.h` and this header includes `afxv_w32.h` which contains following code:

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS_
    #error WINDOWS.H already included. MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>
#endif
...
#include <windows.h>
```

So, if you include `windows.h` before MFC headers, you'll get this error generated in compile time and, as you can see, if you include `afxwin.h` you don't need to include `windows.h` yourself - it will already be included by `afxv_w32.h`.

Answer (score 2):

Because in MFC you are not supposed to use it directly. AFAIR you should include afx.h instead, which in turn indirectly includes windows.h the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

You can include `windows.h`; but you need to first include `afx.h` (or similar).  If you got the error: "MFC apps must not #include <Windows.h>"; it is from including something like `afx.h` after including `windows.h`.

You might need to turn on 'show includes' if not sure how it got included.