# fatal error C1189: #error : WINDOWS.H already included. MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, sql-server-ce, stdafx.h

I have a Visual  Studio 6.0 project that uses SQL Compact Server.
I'm trying to update the solution to use on Visual Studio 2012, but i have the following error:

```
fatal error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>
```

My stdafx.h includes winsock2.h, who have this:

```
#ifndef _INC_WINDOWS
#include <windows.h>
#endif /* _INC_WINDOWS */
```

There is a way to supress the error? How do I proceed? When I remove the windows.h of the files that include it indirectly, I got `error C2011: 'IRowsetBookmark' : 'struct' type redefinition`

I already saw other questions here about this error, but none of suggestions works for me.

---

**- update:**

I solve the `error C2011: 'IRowsetBookmark' : 'struct' type redefinition` adding the following lines in the top of my stdafx.h:

```
#if !defined(__IRowsetBookmark_INTERFACE_DEFINED__)
#define __IRowsetBookmark_INTERFACE_DEFINED__
#endif

#if !defined(__IRowsetBookmark_FWD_DEFINED__)
#define __IRowsetBookmark_FWD_DEFINED__
#endif
```

But i got `error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'`
On those line:

```
class CArrayRowset :
    public CVirtualBuffer<T>,
    public TRowset
{
```

Is it possible that adding that lines on my stdfx.h i messed up some class declaration?

Comment: Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5027152/2802841), wouldn't including `afx.h` or `afxwin.h` just before including `winsock2.h` possibly solve the issue?

Comment: with this i got error C2011: 'IRowsetBookmark' : 'struct' type redefinition that i mentioned

Comment: As for the C2143, I think it's probably unrelated, isn't there an: `error C2504: 'CVirtualBuffer' : base class undefined` just before that? That would mean you have to include the file that defines it, which, at least on VS2013, seems to be `atldbcli.h`.

Comment: this error happens in atldbcli_ce.h

Answer (score 1):

try define _INC_WINDOWS before including winsock2.h to void including win.h

Comment: this _INC_WINDOWS is defined on windows.h

Comment: Is this project supposed to be a MFC project? If not, you need to create a non-MFC project.